# Error reading XML file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

```
            Person person = GetPerson();
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
            string personText = string.Empty;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, new XmlWriterSettings() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 }))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, person, ns);
                    xmlWriter.Flush();
                    personText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
            }

            string path = @"D:\person.xml";
// Write method 1:
            File.WriteAllText(path, personText);

// Write method 2:
            using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false , Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(personText);
            }

// Read the xml
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                return XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(fileStream));
            }
```

When I read the xml after writing using method 2, I get this Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. But it works fine using method 1.

What is causing this? Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Have you compared the two files using a diff tool?

Comment: Have you tried passing `Encoing.UTF8` to the `File.WriteAllText` method as a third argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that both the `StreamWriter` *and* the `XmlWriter` are adding a byte-order-mark.

Options:

- String the BOM from `personText` to start with
- Pass `new UTF8Encoding(false)` instead of `Encoding.UTF8` for the `StreamWriter`
- Pass `new UTF8Encoding(false)` instead of `Encoding.UTF8` for the `XmlWriter`
- Avoid converting to text and back again in the first place: you've got the binary data in the `MemoryStream`, why not just dump *that* to disk?

Comment: Thanks! I need it to be string, so 2nd did the trick. How do I do option 1?

Comment: @Sam: You'd need something like `personText = personText.TrimStart('\feff');` - or change the encoding you pass into `XmlWriter` (I'll add that as an option)